# Writing htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I need help in making this htaccess rewrite rule

Suppose I have this url http://test.com/new.php?code=6789767897879&channel=1432

I need to make it http://test.com/live/6789767897879/1432.m3u8 where code and channel number are variable

So far I tried this with no luck but it keeps giving me no page found.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/live/(.*)/(.*)?$ /new.php?code=$1&channel=$2
```

I am sorry but I am a beginner. Any effort is appreciated. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with your shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^live/([^/]*)/([^.]*)\.m3u8/?$ new.php?code=$1&channel=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Where is new.php? Thanks

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim, `I need to make it http://test.com/live/6789767897879/1432.m3u8 where code and channel number are variable` I should ask you rather :) you haven't mentioned in your question. Where exactly it should be? Kindly do mention.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it is the in /var/www/html the default apache directory. It is in the same directory of the .htaccess file

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim, Could you please try my edited code now and let me know how it goes?

Comment: Working Like a Charm. You are the best!

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim, your welcome, cheers and keep learning and keep sharing on this great site :)